# How to show only description without image on blogger

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger

I have a blog where I want to do something but that may wrong.
Now this attribute `<data:post.body/>` getting the whole post body. But I want to do something like this  `<data:post.description/>`. Is there any way to show only blog description not meta description. If you want to check my blog here is the link you can check and help me.
https://mamutemplates.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `<data:post.snippet/>` instead. Or, you can use `<b:eval expr='data:post.snippets.short snippet { length: 87 }'/>` too.

Comment: not working I need to show full description except body image.